# How to hide the hidden fields values from the page source changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, gridview, hidden-field

I have set of required hidden fields in my `gridview` like this :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_tc" Value='<%# Eval("term_code") %>' runat="server" />
```

---

The problem is the code is clear and shown for every one view the page source .

Is there some way to hide this code i mean even make it in a view state shape .

I use hidden field to : just when i click in the button in the gridview row then set session variables with these hidden fields values and open the specific page .

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: why you  don't use CommandArgument property of your button?

Comment: I use it to store the GV index .

`CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'`

Comment: CommandArgument='<%#(((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex).ToString()+";"+(Eval("term_code")).ToString() %>' and after from code string[] str = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');